# In matplotlib, how to use a secondary axis that is input to the function together with the primary axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function with two arguments (`x1`, `x2`). I would like to plot the function with its result on the y axis, `x1` on the x axis and `x2` on the right y axis (secondary axis).

My problem is that the values of the `x1` and `x2` axes do not correspond together to the function point.

For example:

[image: Example chart]

I want the value read on the primary y axis to match the `x1` and `x2` inputs of the other two axes.

Code:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)

f = lambda x1, x2: np.exp(-x1) / 10 + np.exp(-x2) / 10

resp = []
for i, j in zip(x1, x2):
    resp.append(f(i, j))
resp = np.array(resp)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x1, resp)

ax1.set_xlabel('(x1)')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylabel('(y)')

ax2.set_ylabel('(x2)')
ax2.set_yticks(x2)

plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x1), max(x1)))

plt.show()
```

Comment: You'll need a 3D representation like a heatmap, contour plot or surface

Comment: Even if I want to show just one line?

Comment: That line is not the function of two arguments. It looks like one, but it's really not. You just have `x` and some scaling of `x`

Answer (score 1):

If your input arguments are in lockstep, you do not have a function of two arguments. A function of two arguments has two *independent* inputs. Your inputs are dependent, so rather than writing `f(x1, x2)`, you have `f(x, g(x))`, which is just `f'(x)`. In the specific example that you have `x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)`. Rather than writing `x2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)`, you can just write `x2 = 0.5 * x1`. The exponential you have can be written as

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.exp(-x) / 10 + np.exp(-x / 2) / 10
```

Notice that you do not need a function definition or a loop to compute the `y` values. Using a loop defeats the entire purpose of using numpy. Your original five lines could have been reduced to `y = np.exp(-x1) / 10 + np.exp(-x2) / 10` in the same way.

Now if you want to see the secondary `x` values in the plot of `y` vs `x`, you can take a [page out of the tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) and do something like:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_xlabel('(x1)')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylabel('(y)')

ax2 = ax1.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(lambda x: x / 2, lambda x: 2 * x))
ax2.set_xlabel('(x2)')
plt.show()
```

The result shows "both" inputs in lockstep:

[image]

Now if you really did want to have a function of two variables, then any combination of the inputs would produce a valid `y` value. In this case, you would have to use a feature of numpy called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), which matches array dimensions by lining them up on the right.

Let's say you defined one of the inputs as a transpose:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)                # Shape   (10,)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 10).reshape(-1, 1)  # Shape (10, 1)
```

The result of an operation on these values will be a `(10, 10)` 2D array. Now you can meaningfully compute `y` as function of two independent variables:

```
y = np.exp(-x1) / 10 + np.exp(-x2) / 10
```

To plot such an array, you will need two x-axes and a y-axis, in other words a 3D plot. Here is one way to display something like that in matplotlib:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
s = ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, y, cm=cm.jet)
ax.set_xlabel('(x1)')
ax.set_ylabel('(x2)')
ax.set_zlabel('(y)')
fig.colorbar(s)
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

It is up to you which representation of a function you want.

Comment: Thank you. In reality this function of my question is just an example (bad choice), because my original function is a quite long and I thought it would not be necessary to include it here. The original function does contain independent variables. I used a loop to make sure I have only the responses from the pairs in the sequence.

Comment: @delavald. My answer literally covers both situations. If you have pairs in a sequence, you don't have a function of two variables. Not for the sample you're plotting.

Comment: You can plot a line in 3D, part of the surface I show, or you can plot `x2` as a function of `x1`. Are you asking about the latter?

Comment: Yes. I would like to draw a line, but without the 3D representation. But showing the three axes in the 2D representation.

Comment: My first example shows you how to do that. You can replace the tick conversion functions with whatever you want. Is there something I can improve or elaborate?

Comment: Also, if your actual case uses a much more complicated function, could you post that just for reference? As well as a better approximation of the relationship between x1 and x2? The key here is to find and invert the relationships `y = f_1(x1)`, `y = f_2(x2)`, `x2 = g(x1)`